# Write a short program in SNOBOL that calculate the sum of all even integers from 1 to 100

Tags: snobol

You should use loop for multiple iterations of addition. GOTO statement and labels can be used to design a loop of your requirement. 
please give me some ideas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a zero-effort requirements dump.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not really Snobol if it doesn't contain a pattern match...

This solution generates the even numbers `000 .. 100` by matching a pattern against the string `"01012345678902468"` and adding the generated numbers through the function `add()`. Looping is done through the `FAIL` keyword at the end of the pattern, which forces the pattern scanning to continue looking for alternatives until the expression `(*EQ(h t o,100) ABORT)` causes the scanning to abort.

```
    &FULLSCAN = 1
    DEFINE('add(x)') :(add.End);add sum = sum + x :(RETURN);add.End
    "01012345678902468" (LEN(1) $ h *LEN(1 - h)) ARB (LEN(1) $ t 
.       *LEN(9 - t)) ARB LEN(1) $ o *add(h t o) 
.       (*EQ(h t o,100) ABORT) FAIL
    OUTPUT = sum
END
```

Works both in Snobol and Spitbol (`&FULLSCAN = 1` is needed for Snobol, it's a no-op in Spitbol)

Comment: And in all honesty, I really enjoyed writing this solution, but it's also really convoluted. So the solution Eben posted is better if "written in Snobol" is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

*This works on the Spitbol version of Snobol.

loop m = le(n, 98) (n = n + 2) + m  :s(loop); output = m ;end